# Laravel mail Email subjce is alwasy empty

Tags: laravel

I'm studying contact from.

this is working great but one thing. email subject is always empty.

I wrote below code. Could someone teach me right code right?

```
   Contact::create($request->all());

    \Mail::send('mail', array(
        'phone' => $request->get('phone'),

    ), function($message) use ($request){
        $message->from($request->email);
        $message->to('mail@mmmmail.com', 'subject title')->bcc('mail2@mmmmail.com')->subject($request->get('subject title'));
    });
```

Comment: first check what you are getting in $request->get('subject title') ?? is it empty?

Comment: `$message->to('mail@mmmmail.com', 'subject title')->bcc('mail2@mmmmail.com')->subject('subject title');`

Comment: Dear @sta Thank you! it worked now! I appreciate you always help me!

Comment: Dear @Palak Jadav Thank you for answering me! I totally forgot $request part. Thank you!